# Can’t an image count as name in Schema.org Microdata?

Tags: html, schema.org, microdata

So far I have

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product"><span itemprop="image" class="fn"><img src="<?php echo $product['thumb']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $product['name']; ?>" /></span></div>
```

I understand that the `fn` is supposed to be a value as in `<span class="fn">Name</span>`, but doesn't an image count as one?

Syntax's: http://schema.org/Product

Answer (score 0):

Name has the type Text.

That means that the subelement should be a text node, hence you cannot nest other elements, such as an < img ... /> element.

Answer (score 0):

The `image` property expects a URL as value. You have to use it on an element like `img` (or `a` etc.), but not on `span`.

Note that `class` names aren’t relevant for Microdata and/or Schema.org. `fn` appears to be a value of a Microformat (which is something different than Microdata).